# ArcPy script joins two layers together but leaves out some fields

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I adopted a python script from a coworker who left the company.

I need the missing fields added back in. Is there another process I could use to ensure that all fields from both layers are included? In the code below the "/GIEQ" fc has the needed fields but the "/GIEQ_BG" feature class does not.

```py
#make feature layers and select block groups that intersect the GIEQ polygons

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(thisWorkspace + "/AllBG", "BG_Layer")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(thisWorkspace + "/GIEQ", "GIEQ_Layer")

#clip the block groups to the city limits

in_features = thisWorkspace + "/AllBG"
clip_features = CityLimits
out_feature_class = thisWorkspace + "/AllBG_City"
xy_tolerance = ""
arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, xy_tolerance)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("BG_Layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "Community1 IS NOT NULL")
    
#create a feature class that just contains the GIEQ block groups

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("BG_Layer", thisWorkspace + "/GIEQ_BG")

#clip the qualified block group to the city limits

in_features = thisWorkspace + "/GIEQ_BG"
clip_features = CityLimits
out_feature_class = thisWorkspace + "/GIEQ_BG_City"
xy_tolerance = ""
arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, xy_tolerance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is nothing in your code limiting which fields are being used.
2. In your question you say the FeatureClass GIEQ has the fields but the GIEQ_BQ does not. I suspect that's because GIEQ is referenced on the second line of your code but never used and GIEQ_BQ is actually a copy of the BG_Layer.